# update the ssl certificate on nginx through certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have a site which is running on https with godaddy ssl certificate (paid certificate) which is valid for 1 year.
Not that certificate is expiring on 13-08-2021.

I got the renew certificate.

My question is how I have to do update on nginx so that my site will not down and its ssl certificate is extend.

I am using the ubuntu machine & using the NGINX server.
For SSL I am using the certbot to manage.

certificate is on path

```
/etc/domain.com/domain.com.chained.crt
/etc/domain.com/domain.com.key
```

On my nginx server part of SSL it is written like this

```
ssl_certificate /etc/domain.com/domain.com.chained.crt
ssl_certificate /etc/domain.com/domain.com.key
```

Should I renew now or wait to expire and then renew. I think there is some mechanism by which it should be done before expiry so that user will not suffer.

If I am using the free letsencrypt certificate then I have to use command

```
certbot renew
```

for renew the certifiate. How to deal with this I don't know

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: One thing I have in mind that after expiring the certificate, I will paste the new certificate on same file and restart the server. May be this will refresh and extend the validity.
But this is for the case when certificate expires. Not sure this is correct way or not. And I also want to update before expiry so that user will not suffer

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Certbot/letsencrypt will manage everything for you, without you doing anything - but it generates, and updates, certificates from LetsEncrypt.  If you have a paid certificate from some other authority, certbot can't manage that.  If you have a new paid certificate from someone else, it is up to you to install it, according to their instructions - certbot can't help you with that.

Comment: can you share how to manage this through godaddy

Comment: Whoever you bought your certificate from will have installation instructions.  I searched "*godaddy install ssl certificate*" and found many answers, including GoDaddy's own instructions: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/install-my-ssl-certificate-16623